# Migration of one of two realm instance

Tags: java, android, migration, realm

I'm using two realm instance for different data set.
No.1 realm instance for static data and No.2 realm instance for user data.

I added a new property to one of user data's model, so I migrated #2 realm from schema 0 to 1.

The problem is when I access #1 realm(statics) with no migration code(because nothing's changed #2's models), I get migration exception.

2nd Ream(#2) with migration code succeed with no exception.

Why is this happening? Do I have to feed #1 realm with migration code too?

Following is `RealmConfiguraion` for #1 & #2. And this happens in java and also Obj-C version of Realm.

```
//#1
config =  new RealmConfiguration.Builder(_activity)
                .name("static.realm")
                .build();

//#2
config =  new RealmConfiguration.Builder(_activity)
                .name("user.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all Realm opened in your app will have all of the Object's schema. That means, you still need to migrate #1 even you didn't write any object into it, since the schema exists there.

The solution is separate schemas into different Realms by using [`RealmModule`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/RealmModule.html).

See [document](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas).
And [example](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/moduleExample).